# How to get all rows from multi tables using 1 query

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables (movies, series, lists and list_titles), the question is: How to do to get all movies, series attached to particular list in list_titles table?

Here is what I have done [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0a1e/1).

Query:

```
select *
from (
    select srs.*
    from series srs
    left join list_titles lt on lt.type_id = srs.id
    where lt.list_id = 7
        and lt.type_name = 'series'
        and lt.user_id = 1
    ) as a,
    (
        select mo.*
        from movies mo
        left join list_titles tl on tl.type_id = mo.id
        where tl.list_id = 7
            and tl.type_name = 'series'
            and tl.user_id = 1
        ) as b
```

Comment: Fiddle is great, but we still want table definitions, sample table data and the expected result here - all as well formatted text! And also your current query attempt.

Comment: And don't forget to tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `UNION ALL` between the two queries:

```
select s.id,
    s.title_name,
    ...
from series s
left join list_titles lt on lt.type_id = s.id
where lt.list_id = 7
    and lt.type_name = 'series'
    and lt.user_id = 1

union all

select m.id,
    m.title_name,
    ...
from movies m
left join list_titles tl on tl.type_id = m.id
where tl.list_id = 7
    and tl.type_name = 'series'
    and tl.user_id = 1
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/GNJV43787)

Comment: Or UNION ALL series and movies, and then join that result with titles.

Comment: movies,series tables have not the same number of field

Comment: @Jarlh - Depends. If the series and movies are reasonably large, then I'd join, filter and then union them.

Comment: @Benf - Yes I saw that. If you want to get all of columns then you'll need two separate queryies.

Comment: Well, I don't know which dbms OP is using, but perhaps some dbms products may perform better that way.

Comment: @GurV - I tried what you have posted but I get only 1 row

Comment: @Benf - No. It doesn't. It return 6 rows - 3 from each table. See the added demo in the answer.

Comment: @GurV - don't work well with union all... I changed that with UNION and it worked. thanks, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
  select srs.id, srs.title_name from series srs join 
    (
    select * from list_titles
      where list_id = 7 and type_name = 'series' and user_id = 1
    ) as part1
  on part1.type_id = srs.id
) as a

union

select * from
(
  select mo.id, mo.title_name from movies mo join 
    (
    select * from list_titles
      where list_id = 7 and type_name = 'series' and user_id = 1
    ) as part2
  on part2.type_id = mo.id
) as b;
```

Comment: You can optimize this code by reusing "part1" in place of "part2".